# Spring how to use WebApplicationContex in web.xml

Tags: spring, servlets, web.xml

I work with Spring and I wrote the following web.xml

```
 <web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>configContextLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I execute the web I get the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException
parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appServlet-
servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not  
open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appServlet-servlet.xml]
```

I read in the forums what it is because I need a appServlet-servlet.xml because my servlet is called appServlet.

I have some questions. Do I have call my servlet-context.xml appServlet-servlet.xml?

How can I fix my web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet

From  Spring documentation it says:

**Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your web application**

Change you `servlet-context.xml` to `appServlet-servlet.xml`  and put in under WEB-INF directly.

Better way to bootstrap spring context is to define a listener

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And define the location of Spring context in

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring is not bootstrapped from the web.xml, because you do not have the magic:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I assume you must have some java config or spring boot for that. But as a result, it does not use web.xml configuration.